# com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL

Tags: java, android, android-volley

After making a second network request using Volley, I always get this error. It doesn't seem to matter what the url I put in is.  Volley always claims it is malformed.

```
    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "﻿http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
              Log.e("Data",""+response);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Loi",""+error);

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("DNT","1");
                return params;
            }


        };

        queue.add(sr);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

And then I see following error:

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL ﻿http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: define url you getting data.

Comment: url : http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==

Answer (score 1):

actually the problem is with your url not with the volley. Your Url is not a URI. There is no protocol component in it. It needs http:// or whatever other protocol you intend. If you have the http in your url make sure where it is correctly formed or not.

For example your url formation should be like this

```
public String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
```

Don’t forget to read the below URL Specification with given links and make sure the URL you are providing is valid.

[URL Specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: yeah. url valid : http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==